# Diagonalisation of a quadratic form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, diagonalization

Find a coordinate transformation diagonalizing the quadratic form.[image]

Interesting in answering number 2.
So, here is my approach:-
Step 1:- Write the matrix representation of the equation, that is

A=

```
       1  1  3
       1  1 -3
       3 -3 -3
```

Step 2: After doing this I then use a regular 3x3 matrix diagonalisation procedure. That includes finding the eigen values and vectors, and using this formula :- D=P^-1(A)P. 
Is that the right approach?

Comment: why are you posting what seems to be a test question?

Comment: No, Problem set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diagonalization of a matrix as a linear map is different from a diagonalization of a matrix as a quadratic form. $P^{-1}AP$ is the linear map diagonalization. For a quadratic form, consider the coordinate change $x=P\hat x$, then $p(x)=x^TAx=\hat x^TP^TAP\hat x$, that is we have $P^TAP$ diagonalization instead. It can be done by completing the squares in $p(x)$ or [$LDL$ decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#LDL_decomposition_2).

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395634/given-a-4-times-4-symmetric-matrix-is-there-an-efficient-way-to-find-its-eige/1170390#1170390   where the OP thought it necessary to find eigenvalues, but all that is required is completing the squares (Hermite's method) or this slightly reversed method; the only real difference from Hermite is that one need not invert a matrix at the end

Answer (score 2):

When you complete the squares in $p(x)$ you will get
$$
p(x)=(x_1+x_2+3x_3)^2-3(x_2+3x_3)^2+3x_2^2.
$$
Then with
$$
\tilde x=\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 3\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 1 & 2}x=Px
$$
it becomes
$$
A=P^T\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 3 & 0\\0 & 0 & -3}P.
$$