# $P^{-1}A^{-1}B P$ diagonal implies $P^\top A P$ and $P^\top B P$ diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form, symmetric-matrices

Consider two symmetric positive-definite real matrices $A,B$. $A$ is hence invertible. Denote by $P$ the matrix of the column-eigenvectors of $A^{-1}B$ such that $P^{-1}A^{-1}BP=D$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}B$.

$A^{-1}B$ is symmetric and real, hence can be diagonalized in an orthogonal basis, but this does not mean that $P$ is necessarily orthogonal.

It seems that $P^\top A P$ and $P^\top B P$ are diagonal. Is it always true, and if so, why?

What is not clear to me is the meaning of $P^\top$ instead of $P^{-1}$. I wonder whether this is related to a change of basis (for example, the change of basis of the bilinear forms defined by $A$ and $B$).

---

**Edit** I think this is true only if $A^{-1}B$ has distinct eigenvalues. Indeed, let $v_i$ denote an eigenvector of $A^{-1}B$ for $\lambda_i>0$ (because it is PD), then $A^{-1}B v_i=\lambda_i v_i$ or $Bv_i=\lambda A v_i$ so that $v_j^\top B v_i=\lambda_i v_j^\top A v_i$ and similarly $v_i^\top B v_j=\lambda_j v_i^\top A v_j$. Substracting one equality to the other:
$$ (\lambda_j-\lambda_i)v_i^\top A v_j=(\lambda_j-\lambda_i)v_i^\top \dfrac{1}{\lambda_j}  B v_j.$$ Hence, if $\lambda_i\neq\lambda_j$, necessarily $v_i^\top A v_j=v_i^\top  B v_j=0$ or $V^\top A V$ and $V^\top B V$ are diagonal, where $V$ is a matrix of columns the $v_i$. Does it seem correct?

Comment: It may be helpful to look into the literature on [generalized eigenvalue problems](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/algebra/node7.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is treated in detail in Horn and Johnson; it is their method for finding both  $Q^T AQ$ and $Q^T B Q$ diagonal.

The way you stated it is almost true.  $P^T AP$ and $P^T B P$ may not be diagonal. However, in those locations where either one fails to be diagonal, the other one has a scalar multiple of the same square block. As a result, if necessary, there is an extra adjustment matrix $W$ to finish the job for both, that is both   $W^T P^T APW$ and $W^TP^T B PW$ really are diagonal.

It works without extra effort in this one: [Simultaneous Diagonalization of two bilinear forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697846/simultaneous-diagonalization-of-two-bilinear-forms/1697985#1697985)

One needing extra effort: [Congruence and diagonalizations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88022/congruence-and-diagonalizations)  Note that, while user1551 did the extra step with orthogonal matrices, this was not necessary. For a fixed, symmetric, square matrix (or block) of integers, call it $M,$ there is a quick way to solve $V^T MV$ diagonal, with $V$  all rational entries with determinant $1.$ For this problem, the theorem is that the same $V$ works for both matrices... [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)

For illustration,.here is the square block that needs extra work in the answer by user1551, with my method:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
-2/5 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
5 & 2 \\
2 & 4
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & -2/5 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
5 & 0 \\
0 & 16/5
\end{array}
\right)
$$

This is pages 229 and 231-232 in the first edition, anyway Theorem 4.5.15. I really like their Table 4.5.15T on page 229.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What "square block" are you referring to? You might be interested by the edit: if $A^{-1}B$ has distinct eigenvalues, it seems "there is no need" for $W$.

Comment: @anderstood I encourage you to go through the question I linked with answer by user1551. First, $A^{-1}B$ is not symmetric. Next, repeated diagonal values does not force anything. We could begin with $A,B$ both diagonal and take $P = I.$

Answer (score 4):

As indicated in another answer, this is generally false. What is true, however, that you *can* choose $P$ such that $P^{-1}A^{-1}BP=D$, $P^TAP$, and $P^TBP$ are all diagonal.

Since
$$
A^{-1}B=A^{-1/2}CA^{1/2}, \quad C:=A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2},
$$
where $C$ is SPD, we have $Q^TCQ=D$ for some orthogonal $Q$. Now set $P:=A^{-1/2}Q$ and verify that
$$
P^{-1}A^{-1}BP=Q^TA^{1/2}A^{-1}BA^{-1/2}Q=Q^TCQ=D.
$$
We have $P^TAP=Q^TA^{-1/2}AA^{-1/2}Q=Q^TQ=I$ and
$P^TBP=Q^TA^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2}Q=Q^TQ=D$.

Note that $B$ does not need to be positive definite.

Comment: As a complement, it seems that if $B$ is PD _and_ the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}B$ has distinct eigenvalues, this is always true, see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

If your statement was true it would lead to a contradiction. Take $A=B\succ 0$ to be an arbitrary positive definite matrix, then in this case $A^{-1}B=I$ and for any invertible $P$ we would get $P^{-1}A^{-1}BP=I$. Using the conjectured statement, we would then conclude that $P^{T}AP$ is diagonal which is a contradiction due the arbitrary choice of $A\succ0$ and $P$.

Comment: Your example illustrates the edit in the question: here $A^{-1}B$ does not have distinct eigenvalues.