# What is the method to find this transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Find a transformation that simultaneously reduces

$$Q_{1} = 3X^2_{1}-2X_{1}X_{2}+3X^2_{2}$$ and $$Q_{2}=X_{1}X_{2}$$ a diagonal form.

thanks

Comment: What are $X_1,X_2$?

Comment: you can write the same in this way, as vectors  $$Q_{1} = x_{1}(3x_{1}-x_{2})+x_{2}(3x_{2}-x_{1})$$

Comment: This is possible because $Q_1$ is def. pos. See Lagrange method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3966467)