# Sylvester's argument for bilinear functions

Tags: vector-spaces, bilinear-form

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ and let $b:\colon V \times V\to \mathbb{R}$ be a symmetric bilinear function.

Sylvester's theorem says that there exists a basis of $V$ with respect to which the matrix of $b$ is a diagonal matrix with only $1$, $-1$ and $0$ on the diagonal.

My question is, in order to apply Sylvester's argument do I have to start (using other arguments, for instance Lagrange's method ) from a matrix that is already diagonal and after that, find the basis such that I have just $\pm 1$ and $0$ on the diagonal?

Comment: hint : $M_{ij} = b(e_i,e_j)$. what can you say of $M$ ?

Comment: $M$ is a symmetric matrix... so $M$ is congruent to a diagonal matrix $D$.. in other words there exists a matrix $P$ such that $P^TAP=D$, my question is: how do I find the matrix $D$ and the matrix $P$?

Comment: it is the spectral theorem, or the SVD

Comment: Sorry... what do you mean with SVD?

Comment: Maybe I understood something.... From the spectral theorem I know that the matrix P is orhogonal, this means that $P^T=P^{-1}$, so to find the matrix D it is enough to find the eigenvalues of $A$ and in order to find the matrix $P$ it is enough to find the eigenvectors of $A$...is it right?

Comment: yes  $   $, then you have to answer the main question of the exercice

Comment: So... in order to find the Sylvester basis I have to find first the matrix $D$ through the eigenvalues and the matrix $P$ trough the eigenvectors and after I can transform the matrix $D$ in the Sylvester 's form... Is this correct? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Existence in this case is guaranteed by theorems. In case you wish to perform the task for an actual matrix...

It is not necessary to use eigenvalues in this case. [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia) concerns this:   $P^T AP = D,$ where $A$ is symmetric, $P$ is nonsingular (but NOT necessarily orthogonal) and $D$ is diagonal. This relationship is often called "congruence," especially if we arrange that the determinant of $P$ be equal to one.

The easiest method is essentially "completing the square," associated with Hermite more or less. There is a method that is entirely cookbook; I collected several examples on this site. Note that I did eventually find a recent book that had this, called *Linear Algebra Done Wrong* by [TREIL](https://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/LADW.html). Oh: at the end, you have a diagonal matrix $D.$ One further step, for each nonzero diagonal entry $\lambda$ make another diagonal matrix $Q,$ where the matching element is $1 \sqrt {|\lambda|}.$ Then $Q^T DQ = QTQ$ has diagonal entries all $1,0,-1.$

[reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)

[Bilinear Form Diagonalisation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329304/bilinear-form-diagonalisation)

[Given a $4\times 4$ symmetric matrix, is there an efficient way to find its eigenvalues and diagonalize it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395634/given-a-4-times-4-symmetric-matrix-is-there-an-efficient-way-to-find-its-eige/1170390#1170390)

[Find the transitional matrix that would transform this form to a diagonal form.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388281/find-the-transitional-matrix-that-would-transform-this-form-to-a-diagonal-form/1391117#1391117)

[Writing an expression as a sum of squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515495/writing-an-expression-as-a-sum-of-squares/1516684#1516684)

[Determining matrix $A$ and $B$, rectangular matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540594/determining-matrix-a-and-b-rectangular-matrix)

[Method of completing squares with 3 variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580174/method-of-completing-squares-with-3-variables)

[Using Lagrange's diagonalization on degenerate linear forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597162/using-lagranges-diagonalization-on-degenerate-linear-forms/1597478#1597478)

[a question about a canonical form of a quadratic form using Gauss theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597332/a-question-about-a-canonical-form-of-a-quadratic-form-using-gauss-theorem/1597440#1597440)