# Books about the general equation of the quadrics

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, book-recommendation

I'd like suggestions of books that address the general equation of the quadrics ($Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + Dxy + Exz + Fyz + Gx + Hy + Iz + J = 0$), that is, a book that teach to rotate a quadric and also teach to find what quadric is when it's given rotated .

Answer (score 1):

Suggest Treil [Linear Algebra Done Wrong](https://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/book.pdf).

Next, suggest you add another variable, say $w,$ to arrive at
$$ A x^2 + B y^2 + C z^2 + Dxy + E zx + F yz + G xw + H yw + I zw + J w^2.  $$
The Hessian matrix, $M,$ of second partial derivatives for this is
$$ M =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
2A & D & E & G \\
D & 2B & F & H \\
E & F & 2C & I \\
G & H & I & 2 J
\end{array}
\right)
$$ 
Finally, either for the original polynomial or for this, there is no guarantee of a closed form (radicals) for the eigenvalues. However, these are not necessary. If all the (10?) coefficients are integers, it is guaranteed that there is an invertible matrix $P$ with all coefficients integer or rational, such that
$$ P^T M P = N, $$
where $N$ is diagonal. The diagonal elements of $N$ tell you all you need to know about the type of quadric, even though there is distortion involved. That is, the diagonal entries of $N$ are not the eigenvalues of anything. Finally, there is a simple algorithm for finding such a matrix $P,$ both in the Treil book and at links in [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)

Oh, if you use all four variables, at the end you set $w=1.$

Here is a 4 by 4 with bad eigenvalues: [Given a $4\times 4$ symmetric matrix, is there an efficient way to find its eigenvalues and diagonalize it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395634/given-a-4-times-4-symmetric-matrix-is-there-an-efficient-way-to-find-its-eige/1170390#1170390)  I give an explicit $P$ in my answer there.