# Is the matrix diagonalizable? Explain

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hi so I have this matrix 
              $$\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 4 & 3\\4& 1& 0\\3& 0 & 2\end{matrix}\right]$$ that im trying to find if its digonalizable or not but i cant seem to find the proper eigen values because one of it comes out to be imaginary. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Hint:** Notice that the matrix is symmetric. What does that tell you about its diagonalizability?

Comment: Eigenvalues can be imaginary, but when the entries in the matrix are integers, imaginary or complex roots come in pairs.

Comment: @MarkBennet Doesn't this have more to do with the fact that the entries are real? I mean you are technically right, but it sounds strange to reason that it is because they are integers.

Comment: @M.Winter Indeed real entries is also correct. I learned about matrices before I learned in any rigour about real numbers (strange as it may seem). So I wasn't sure what background I could assume.

Comment: Yes it should be real entries. The reason is, that then the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are real. So by complex-conjugation of the polynomial you can deduce that if $z$ is a root, also $\overline{z}$ is a root.

Comment: It seems that all the eigenvalues are real: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=caracteristic+equation{{0,4,3},{4,1,0},{3,0,2}}

Comment: @EmilioNovati They have to be real, see the answer below.

Comment: Yes, I agree that  ''they have not to be'', but they are  :)

Comment: Hint taken, added `and have real eigenvalues` to the answer. Thanks^^

Comment: I'm still unsure where I'm going wrong. What do the eigen values come out to be?

Comment: So why don't you tell us step-by-step, what you did by editing your question?

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not tell us, where you are stuck, we can't help you with what you struggle.
Hence this answer is minimalistic, but complete.

Real, symmetric matrices are diagonalizable (by orthogonal matrices) and have real eigenvalues. 
And your matrix is real and symmetric.

Have a look at the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).

Comment: in case of interest: sometimes it becomes clear that the student is being asked about congruence rather than similarity (and may post contradictory phrases), see example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395634/given-a-4-times-4-symmetric-matrix-is-there-an-efficient-way-to-find-its-eige

Comment: In this case the question is probably homework or from an (old) exam. It is a typical example, where the calculation of eigenvalues gets pretty ugly, as you can see in the other solution, but the task can be solved in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you're doing the eigenvalue calculation correctly. It should look something like this:

$$\begin{align}
\det\left[\begin{matrix}-\lambda & 4 & 3 \\ 4 & 1- \lambda & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 2-\lambda \end{matrix}\right] &= 3\left|\begin{matrix}4 & 3 \\ 1-\lambda & 0\end{matrix}\right| + (2-\lambda)\left|\begin{matrix}-\lambda & 4 \\ 4 & 1-\lambda\end{matrix}\right|\\
&=3(3(\lambda-1)) +(2-\lambda)((\lambda^2-\lambda)-16)\\
&=9\lambda-9-\lambda^3+3\lambda^2+14\lambda-32 \\
&=-(\lambda^3-3\lambda^2-23\lambda+41)
\end{align}$$

In the first step there, I expanded along the bottom row, because there was a $0$ there. Your steps getting there may differ, but you should arrive at the same polynomial, which has 3 real roots, although they are not nice, rational numbers. They appear to equal approximately $-4.38, 1.62$ and $5.76$.

Double-check your calculation and see if you get the same eigenvalues.

Comment: in case of interest: sometimes it becomes clear that the student is being asked about congruence rather than similarity (and may post contradictory phrases), see example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395634/given-a-4-times-4-symmetric-matrix-is-there-an-efficient-way-to-find-its-eige

Answer (score 0):

For a symmetric matrix $H,$ without bothering about the eigenvalues, the matrix is ***congruent*** to a diagonal matrix, meaning there is a matrix $P$ with $\det P \neq 0$ such that $P^T HP = D$ is diagonal

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 4 & 0 \\ 
4 & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 3 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 16 & 3 \\ 
0 & 3 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 16 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 16 }  \\ 
1 &  - 4 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 16 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D =    \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 16 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 41 }{ 16 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 4 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 16 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 16 }  \\ 
1 &  - 4 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 16 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 41 }{ 16 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 16 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 16 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 41 }{ 16 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 16 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

As happens sometimes, there is a more attractive version available, all integers:

$$ P^T HP = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & -1 & 1 \\ 
-2 & 1 & -1 \\ 
11 &  -3  & 4\\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
4 &   1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 0 &  2   \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & -2 & 11 \\ 
-1 & 1 &  -3  \\ 
1 & -1 & 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 41 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
-1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 7 & 1 \\ 
5 &  8  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  41   \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
-1 & 3 & 5 \\ 
-1 & 7 &  8  \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$