# Determining matrix $A$ and $B$, rectangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $3\times 2$ matrix and $B$ be a $2\times 3$ be matrices satisfying $$AB=\begin{pmatrix} 8 & 2 & -2\\ 2 & 5 & 4\\ -2 & 4 & 5\end{pmatrix}$$
Calculate $BA$. How would you go for this problem? Do we start by noticing the matrix is symmetric? Any hints/ideas? Thanks

Comment: Start with this: given your symmetric $C,$ you can find a very nice $P$ such that $P^T C P$ is diagonal. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395634/given-a-4-times-4-symmetric-matrix-is-there-an-efficient-way-to-find-its-eige/1170390#1170390

Comment: Huh. Never done this problem this way before. You can demand $B = A^T.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a strange problem. In general, the quesiton would not be well posed. As observed in the comment by @JohnMa it is neccesary that the given $3\times 3$-matrix has rank two. This is satisfied, but even then, the question would not be well posed in gerneral. Namely, if $A$ and $B$ are such that $AB$ is your given matrix, then for any invertible $2\times 2$ matrix $T$ also $AT$ and $T^{-1}B$ have the same property. In that way $BA$ gets replaced by $T^{-1}BAT$, which is different from $BA$ in general. Hence the only case in which the question is well posed is if $BA$ is a multiple of the identity matrix, and with the given $3\times 3$-matrix, you indeed get $BA=9I$.

EDIT: I have rewritten and extended the next paragraph a bit, following the remark by @CarlosMendoza:

The way to prove this, is as follows. You first compute the eigenvalues of $AB$ and find that they are $0$ (multiplicity one) and $9$ (multiplicity two). In particular $AB$ has rank two, and viewing it as a linear map $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ its kernel is given by the $0$-eigenspace and its image is given by the $9$-eigenspace. (The first equality holds by definition, while for the second, the eigenspace is obviously contained in the image and has the same dimension.) Now the matrices $A$ and $B$ correspond to linear maps $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^2$, respectively, so they both have rank at most two. By definition, the kernel of $B$ is contained in the kernel of $AB$ and the image of $AB$ is contained in the image of $A$. Since the kernel of $B$ has at least dimension one and the image of $A$ has at most dimension two, both these inclusions must be equalities. In particular, the image of $A$ is the $9$--eigenspace of $AB$, and calling this $V$, $A$ must define a linear isomorphism $\mathbb R^2\to V$. But this immediately implies that $(AB)A=9A$ since $AB$ is multiplication by $9$ on $V$. Rewriting the left hand side as $A(BA)$, you get $A(BAx)=A(9x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^2$, and since $A$ is injective, this implies $BAx=9x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: The reasoning you did in the first paragraph about why $BA$ has to be a multiple of the identity matrix is really elegant and powerful (in just four lines you were the first one to get the main form of the solution!). Unfortunately, it gets a little obscure **to me** (an inexpert that wants to learn more) in the second paragraph when you want to prove why it must be $9$ the integer multiple. Could you extend a little more that proof such that it gets a little more readable for newbies? Also, some references (links) that support your thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this clarfies

Comment: @CarlosMendoza: I have edited the answer. I am not sure about references, I think that I have not used anything special, mainly the general philosophy to think about linear maps rather than matrices ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I don't have time to develop al the exercise, but I think I can give you some hints. After that I think is more or less straight-forward.
Consider
\begin{equation}
A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a & c & e\\
b & d & f\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
B=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
g & h & 0\\
i & l & 0\\
m & n & 0
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
So we have 
\begin{equation}
BA=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
u & v & 0\\
w & z & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
Some invariants are: 
\begin{equation}
trAB=trBA
\end{equation}
And from this we have
\begin{equation}
u+z=18
\end{equation}
Since AB is simmetric so is BA
\begin{equation}
v=w
\end{equation}
The Binet formula shouldn't be so useful because detAB=detBA=0
Anyway I think that from here more or less You can proceed with direct calculation.Let me know.

Comment: It isn't necessarily true that $\det AB = \det BA$ when dealing with non-square matrices.  For example, if $v$ is a non-zero real vector, $v^Tv$ is a $1\times 1$ non-zero matrix, while $vv^T$ is a rank one matrix.  If $v\in \mathbb R^n$ with $n>0$, then one of the determinants is zero and the other is not.  However, this is this is all that can go wrong: up to a factor of $t^k$, $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestion of @WillJagy and the direct approach suggested by @Dac0, we have
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
e & f\\
\end{bmatrix}\qquad
B =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c & e\\
b & d & f\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and from $AB$ we get the following set of equations

\begin{align}
a^2 + b^2 &= 8\\
c^2 + d^2 &= 5\\
e^2 + f^2 &= 5\\
ac + bd &= 2\\
ae + fb &= -2\\
ec + fd &= 4\\
\end{align}

I solved this in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%3D8%2C+a*c%2Bb*d%3D2%2C+a*e%2Bf*b%3D-2%2C+c%5E2%2Bd%5E2%3D5%2C+e*c%2Bf*d%3D4%2C+e%5E2%2Bf%5E2%3D5) and tested with this particular solution(out of infinite solutions):

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -2\\
-2 & 1\\
-1 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}\qquad
B =
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -2 & -1\\
-2 & 1 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Interestingly enough,

$$BA =
\begin{bmatrix}
9 & 0\\
0 & 9\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which corresponds to the solution proposed by @AndreasCap. It's also interesting to note that the columns of $A$ are orthogonal and their squared length are equal to $9$, the non-zero eigenvalue of $AB$ with multiplicity $2$.

I gave importance to @WillJagy suggestion because somehow it remembered me of the [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Properties). I am not saying is the same, but there are nice similarities.

Comment: Having $B=A^T$ was possible because the given three by three symmetric matrix was positive semidefinite. Once you make that decision, even though rectangular, the trace of $AA^T$ equals the trace of $A^T A,$ the sum of the squares of all entries of $A.$

Comment: Posted an answer entirely from the viewpoint of integer quadratic forms, traditional Hermite reduction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was the most straightforward way hoever, this question is not well posed

Comment: Your welcome nerd, although I would say that the problem is well posed under some special conditions, as was analyzed by Andreas Cap, and derived by Will Jagy and me :)

Answer (score 1):

Afterthought: Hermite reduction, which is nothing worse than "completing the square" a few times, works for indefinite quadratic forms as well; the resulting diagonal matrix then has some negative entries. Since the quadratic form in this problem is positive semidefinite, it is possible to continue, in the end I found $W^T W = C,$ where $C$ is the given 3 by 3 matrix and $W$ is 2 by 3.

Given that the matrix (I am calling it $C$) has integer entries and is symmetric, it is natural to investigate "congruence" diagonalization of it, that is finding a rational matrix $P$ of determinant $1,$ such that
$$ P^T C P = D $$  is diagonal. I am actually going to save some time by going directly to Hermite reduction, finding a rational matrix $R$ of determinant $1,$ such that
$$ R^T D R = C, $$ where we construct $D$   diagonal. Note $R= P^{-1}.$

Take a column vector 
$$  
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}
\right)
$$

With
$$C=\begin{pmatrix} 8 & 2 & -2\\ 2 & 5 & 4\\ -2 & 4 & 5\end{pmatrix}$$ we get
$$ v^T C v = 8 x^2 + 5 y^2 + 5 z^2 + 8 y z - 4 z x + 4 x y $$
Hermite reduction says to start with $8 (x+ \mbox{stuff})^2$ to get rid of all the $x$ terms, those being $8x^2 - 4 zx+ 4 x y.$ And we find
$$ 8 (x + \frac{y}{4} -  \frac{z}{4})^2 = 8 x^2 +  \frac{y^2}{2}+  \frac{z^2}{2} - y z - 4 z x + 4 x y $$
You really can do this by hand!
$$ v^T C v - 8 (x + \frac{y}{4} -  \frac{z}{4})^2 =   \frac{9y^2}{2} +   \frac{9z^2}{2} + 9 y z. $$

Second step: get rid of $y^2$ and $yz$ terms, with $(9/2)(y + ??)^2$
And
$$ \frac{9}{2} (y+z)^2 =   \frac{9y^2}{2} +   \frac{9z^2}{2} + 9 y z. $$
Hermite's method ends early, because 
$$ v^T C v = 8 \left(x + \frac{y}{4} -  \frac{z}{4} \right)^2 +  \frac{9}{2} (y+z)^2 $$

So far, we have found (this becomes quick if you do quadratic forms all day)
$$
D = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
8 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{9}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
R = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
such that
$$  R^T D R = C.  $$ Check!

Now, can we write $D$ as $H^T H?$ Yes, of course, it is positive semidefinite, we could use

$$
H = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\sqrt 8 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt {\frac{9}{2}} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
However, $8 \cdot (9/2) = 36$ is a square;  it is much prettier if we note that both $8$ and $9/2$ can be expressed as $u^2 + v^2$ with rational $u,v.$ Indeed, both are $2 u^2,$ in that $2 \cdot 2^2 = 8$ and $2 \cdot \left( \frac{3}{2}\right)^2 = 9/2.$

I thought of a nicer way to put this bit. $$ 2 \left(8 u^2 + \frac{9}{2} v^2 \right) = 16 u^2 + 9 v^2 = (4u)^2 + (3v)^2. $$ In general,
$$  2 \left(A^2 + B^2 \right) = (A-B)^2 + (A+B)^2, $$
$$  \frac{1}{2} \left(A^2 + B^2 \right) = \left( \frac{A-B}{2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{A+B}{2} \right)^2, $$
$$  \frac{1}{2} \left((4u)^2 + (3v)^2 \right) = \left( \frac{4u-3v}{2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{4u+3v}{2} \right)^2, $$
$$   8 u^2 + \frac{9}{2}v^2 = \left( \frac{4u-3v}{2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{4u+3v}{2} \right)^2. $$
This means we can take

$$
H = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 &  -\frac{3}{2} & 0 \\
2 &  \frac{3}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
In the language of integral quadratic forms, we say that $8 u^2 + \frac{9}{2}v^2$ is rationally represented by $s^2 + t^2;$ we have written
$$ \left( 2 u  -\frac{3}{2} v \right)^2 + \left( 2 u  +\frac{3}{2} v \right)^2 = 8 u^2 + \frac{9}{2}v^2$$

Now, we don't want to keep $H$ 3 by 3, we get the same $K^T K = D$ with $K$ 2 by 3 with

$$
K = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 &  -\frac{3}{2} & 0 \\
2 &  \frac{3}{2} & 0 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
by simply deleting the final row of zeroes.

We have $K^T K = D$ and $R^T D R = C.$ Put them together,
$$ C = R^T (K^T K) R =  R^T K^T K R =  (R^T K^T) K R = (KR)^T (KR).$$
We make a new matrix name,
$$ W = K R $$ which is 2 by 3 and solves
$$ W^T W = C. $$

$$
\color{blue}{
W = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 &  -1 & -2 \\
2 &  2 & 1 
\end{array}
\right)}
$$

They want the reversed product,

$$
W W^T = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
9 &  0  \\
0 &  9  
\end{array}
\right)
$$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Similar:

[reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)

[Bilinear Form Diagonalisation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329304/bilinear-form-diagonalisation)

[Given a $4\times 4$ symmetric matrix, is there an efficient way to find its eigenvalues and diagonalize it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395634/given-a-4-times-4-symmetric-matrix-is-there-an-efficient-way-to-find-its-eige/1170390#1170390)

[Find the transitional matrix that would transform this form to a diagonal form.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388281/find-the-transitional-matrix-that-would-transform-this-form-to-a-diagonal-form/1391117#1391117)

[Writing an expression as a sum of squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515495/writing-an-expression-as-a-sum-of-squares/1516684#1516684)

Comment: Nice answer Will. It would be great if you put in it some links to (hopefully open) references  about this Hermite method and the quadratic forms.

Comment: @CarlosMendoza, thanks. I will need to think about links not on this site, but I have a list of several questions on this site I can paste in. I keep an ordinary text file on my home computer, for areas that come up often for me, I collect the URL's in the file. Quicker than the "Favorites" facility in my profile because organized by topic rather than time of posting.

Comment: I think those references are enough Will, thanks!